# Is it possible to extend the prototype of a specific tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, safari, opera

Putting aside debates over extending prototypes, I would like to know if it's possible to extend the prototype of a specific tag. Preferably cross-browser.

For example: I know you can extend all tags by using "HTMLElement.prototype" or just the <video> tags by using "HTMLVideoElement.prototype", but what about unknown tags like <track>?

Comment: unknown tags are also HTMLElement...

Comment: Check out [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement). If you're adding a method, and only want it to affect certain custom elements, you could test the `.tagName` property as needed. Not sure of browser support, though it does look like it's supported in IE8 according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a `HTMLTrackElement.prototype` that can be used.

Comment: I had this idea originally, but wouldn't this mean that every unknown element would receive the method/property?

Comment: Yes, but that's where you'd test the `.tagName`, assuming you're adding a method or a getter/setter. Just do `switch (this.tagName.toUpperCase()) { case "FOO"; /* do something */ break; case "BAR": /* do something else */ break; default: console.log(this.tagName, " not supported"); }`

Comment: I just had a quick test and it works fine. Would you know what the performance impacts would be like?

Comment: Minimal, but only testing will tell. Ultimately, if this is a feature you need, don't worry about the performance unless it proves to be an issue.